# Trigger Error on MSSQL with an OPENQUERY to Linked Server with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, triggers, odbc, linked-server

i got the following issue:

i got a server running Win Server 2000 / MSSQL Server 20000 (Don`t ask why), i have in the MSSQL server a linked server who has MySQL 5.1.

My linked server works fine, i did openquerys on it and works perfect, the problem is when i try to associate some OPENQUERY to a particular trigger.

What i need to do is to sync both databases, for example, if i do an insert on MSSQL, the trigger should take that data and insert it on the linked server with MYSQL.

The error i got is the following:

> Servidor: mensaje 7391, nivel 16, estado 1, procedimiento
>   items_insert, línea 5 No se puede realizar la operación. El proveedor
>   OLE DB 'MSDASQL' no pudo iniciar una transacción distribuida. [OLE/DB
>   provider returned message: [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Optional feature
>   not supported]

The spanish part says something like " The operation can`t be done, The OLE DB 'MSDASQL' couldn`t start a distributed transaction"

hope someone can guide me trought this!

Comment: Have you read this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306212/en-us?

Comment: Does the MySQL database need to be up to the second, or can it be a minute or five minutes behind? Have you considered creating views on the MySQL side instead of trying to keep two copies?

Comment: i also need to create a web based software using the mysql data, will the views work for that purpose?

Comment: @Igor yes, i´ve already check that, and got the same error, the thing is that i can do querys on the mysql server trought mssql, is not working only when i put the code inside a trigger after an insert